# Representing Table with DIV

Tags: html, css, html-table

I had a table

```
<td colspan="6">
    <table width="100%" border="0">
      <tr align="center">
        <td width="5%"><input type="checkbox" name="chkAll" class="chkAll" value="1" /></td>
        <td width="7%"><strong>Item Id </strong></td>
        <td width="20%"><strong>Item</strong></td>
        <td width="17%"><strong>Type</strong></td>
        <td width="17%"><strong>Rate</strong></td>
        <td width="17%"><strong>Quantity</strong></td>
        <td width="17%"><strong>Price</strong></td>
      </tr>
```

I am representing the table through `<DIV>` like This

```
<div id="table">
             <div class="row" id="row" align="center">
                <div id="cell"><input type="checkbox" name="chkAll" class="chkAll" value="1" /></div>
                <div id="cell"><strong>Item Id </strong></div>
                <div id="cell"><strong>Item</strong></div>
                <div id="cell"><strong>Type</strong></div>
                <div id="cell"><strong>Rate</strong></div>
                <div id="cell"><strong>Quantity</strong></div>
                <div id="cell"><strong>Price</strong></div>
             </div>
```

but I can't find any replacement for `colspan="6"`. Can anyone help?

Comment: There is no equivalent for `div` because a `div` has no concept of "columns" (it is a generic block tag). The correct question is why? Tables are for tabular data, which you have here. What would be the benefit of converting it to a div, which is a generic block element?

Comment: Nesting tables like that is never a good idea. ou should probably rethink your structure. And no, replacing all elements with divs is not the solution.

Comment: If you have tabular data, use `<table>`! You just should not use `<table>` for mere layout purposes.

Comment: That looks like tabular data. Hence, you should use a `<table>`. Why are you trying to change to `<div>`s? Bad idea.

Comment: You should use `th` (with `scope="col"` attribute and value I guess) and not `td` in your first example: they seem like the headers for the rest of your tabular data.

Answer (score 3):

OK, let's get this straight for the 100th time.

### Tables are not evil.

Tables are for tabular data. If you have headers, rows or columns, then it's cool. Tables are the thing to use.

In HTML. Tables.

### Misusing elements is evil

Using any element for the wrong reason is wrong.

`h1` for images

`table` for layout

`button` for links

These things are wrong. And bad.

### Summary

Use tables for tables, not for layout, and everyone will be happy.

Comment: +1 but I didn't understand "h1 for images (is evil)". `h1>img[alt]` seems fine to me, if it's a real heading and if it can't be done in CSS (when WCAG2 Technique C30 http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/C30.html ) can't be applied)

Comment: Yeah, good point. I must admit that it did cross my mind when I wrote it. Perhaps imagine that every image on the page was an H1.

Comment: Oh the sort of CMS where everything is an image created server-side? OK I'm glad I don't work or see this sort of creepy/crappy project :)

Answer (score 1):

Div do not use concept of columns. You can have as many as you want, div's in a row. You can fix width of div and then can use them to build up table. By the way you can go for css framework like bootstrap will be much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Make the div width in such a way that, it will occupy "TD" sections.

For that you just need to add one more class with some higher width in it and some less div on the new row.